# Best data structure to use for finding words with similar meaning

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I was designing dictionary using Binary Tree Data structure. However I have requirement to find similar meaning words from the Binary Tree Data Structure. I am wondering if Binary tree data structure can modify to achieve it or is there other data structure support this requirement

Comment: Will words of similar meaning all belong to the same group? I.e. if A is similar to B and to C, then B is also similar to C? Or are words to be compared using some sort of characteristic vector, where a small enough distance constitutes "likeliness"?

Comment: for example, puppy is a similar word for dog. so if i give dog as input , i should  get puppy as output for similar words

Comment: Yes. But if "race" is similar to both "competition" and "ethnicity", then clearly "competition" still isn't similar to "ethnicity". So how do you treat this case? Do you consider the two meanings of "race" to be different words?

Comment: Actually, I didn't though about it. My initial question was how to do the basic similarity match. Based on what you said I understand that what u have explained could happen. But it is not that important to me at this stage and good to have feature.

Comment: I think this type of problem I posed, along with a few others, actually governs how you treat similarity. But based on what I think you're saying, you should just do whatever you did previously, but instead of storing actual words in the nodes, you store Hashsets of similar words.

Comment: As a side note, what made you choose a BST data structure for this task, instead of say a HashMap or Trie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Disjoint Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure to build preliminary data.

Every pack of synonyms will have the main representative word. If two words share the same representative, they are synonyms.

When all vocabulary words are assigned to groups, fill the map (dictionary, hashmap) with lists containing groups. Key for every word is representative.

So to get synonyms for given word, you have to:
-take representative for this word
-find map entry for this representative
-extract list of synonyms from this map entry

Of course, homonyms (different meanings of the same word), as Christofer Ohlsson noticed, make the problem harder.